# how can I create new ID column using R

Tags: r

I am working on csv file and trying to assign new id of rows with No ID of the whole csv file.

```
what I have          I would like to create NewID Number
Id number   ------->      NewId number
1245                        1245
1367                        1367
NoID                        NoID_1
1468                        1468
NoID                        NoID_2
NoID                        NoID_3
1456                        1456
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to convert to `numeric` to find the ones that are not numeric

```
i1 <- is.na(as.numeric(df1[["ID number"]]))
df1$NewId <- df1[["ID number"]]
df1$NewId[i1] <- paste0(df1[["ID number"]][i1], "_", seq(sum(i1)))
```

Or if we don't want to get warning message by the conversion to numeric, use a regex pattern

```
i1 <- !grepl("^\\d+$", df1[["ID number"]])
```

#### data

```
df1 <-structure(list(`ID number` = c("1245", "1367", "NoID", "1468", 
"NoID", "NoID", "1456")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. it's very useful. It works, but New Id order is not accurate. e.g NoID   ----> 1245_1, but I want to be NoID_1.

Comment: @Dreamer_y19th thanks, I didn't test earlier.  There were some typos.  Corrected.  Please check